# iPhone iOS createUUID leaking memory with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting, uuid

I have a little method I found on the web that creates universally unique identifiers (UUID). The xCode static analyzer tells me that this method is leaking memory where it is marked in the code below.

**Can someone tell me what's the correct way to write this code so there's no memory leak?**

```
    +(NSString *)createUUID
    {

        // Create universally unique identifier (object)
        CFUUIDRef uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

        // Get the string representation of CFUUID object.
//leak here
        NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject) ;

        CFRelease(uuidObject);

        return uuidStr;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
```

You need to tell the NSString it is responsible for the ownership of the created CFString. This way, if you have ARC turned on, the CFString will be freed up automatically. If you use __bridge instead you will need to explicitly call CFRelease to release the CFString created by the *Create function call.

For more information about the `__bridge` casts read the [Casting and Object Lifetime Semantics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677-SW2) section of Apple's [Core Foundation Design Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122-SW1) Guide.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `__bridge`:

```
NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject) ;
```

Use `CFBridgingRelease`. Your use of `__bridge` here is wrong. You are telling ARC that it has no memory management responsibilities with `uuidStr`. But it does have such responsibilities, because of the `Create` in the name of the function `CFUUIDCreateString`. ARC needs to add a release to correspond with the `Create`. Otherwise you will leak. You must tell ARC about this. `CFBridgingRelease` is the easiest way to do this.

For more, see the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management_of_cftyperefs

Comment: Or change `__bridge` to `__bridge_transfer`.

Comment: @rmaddy WWDC 2012 video gave me the distinct impression they were preferring the CFBridgingXXX functions over the rather confusingly named `__bridge_xxx` designations. And so do I!

Comment: @matt Personally I think `__bridge_transfer` is much clearer than `CFBridgingRelease`. The former makes it very clear (to me) that ownership is being transferred.

Comment: Chacun à son goût, but the notion of "transfer of ownership" does not explain to me where we are in the management of this thing's memory. Whereas, the name `CFBridgingRelease` is clear and explicit: this is the CFRelease that balances the implicit CFRetain from the Create. So my obligation to CFType memory management is now complete, and ARC is now in control and I can take my hands off the tiller.